# How to make picturebox trigger mousedoubleclick?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using a Win Form VS 2010 C#.

I have the following code on the Form Load

```
pictureBox2.MouseClick +=new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox2_Click);
pictureBox2.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(pictureBox2_Click);
pictureBox2.Click += new EventHandler(pictureBox2_Click);
pictureBox2.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox2_Click);
```

and this on the Event

```
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Hides and disables another picture box
    pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
    pictureBox1.Visible = false;
    // more codes here...
}
```

It does not want to fireup the Event. I've even added the toggle breakpoint just to be sure but it never stops there.

My pictureBox2 has a property BackColor Transparent. Does this have anything to do with it?

Comment: what event do you want, you have `Click`, `DoubleClick` and `MouseDoubleClick`, its been a long time since the Winform days but I am sure the `Click` event is a `EventHandler` not a `MouseEventHandler`.

Comment: I've even added Click just now, none of the Event Handlers works. Editing code

Comment: Did you verify (breakpoint) that your `Form_Load` actually gets called?

Comment: it does pass through the += as per debug but does not execute the event.

Comment: Here is my complete code at this [link](http://pastebin.com/AWrEfxK5)

Comment: @HenryHughes you may not know that your problem is **very strange**, you should try an empty project and test it there, you can also try `rebuild` your project. I guess you might run your project once in error and a dialog appeared asking you to run the last successfully built version or not and you might choose `Yes`, then every updated code won't be built if you just click `Run and debug`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like everything should work, so my thoughts are:

1. What happens if you use .Click instead of .MouseClick?  Any difference?
2. What happens if you move the event handler creation into InitializeComponent() (or right after InitializeComponent()) instead of in the form load event?  Any difference?
3. Is there some sort of issue with another control on top of your picture box receiving the click instead of your picturebox?
4. If you suspect that the transparent backcolor might be a problem, why not change it and see if that fixes the problem?  Then you'll have your answer.
5. (**SOLUTION**) EDIT added for clarification after @HenryHughes commented that he eventually solved the original problem by simply re-creating the Visual Studio project from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for respond. Here is my observation.
1. none of the four events works.
2. putting it both on InitialComponent and FormLoad actual runs the += for all event. Both however does not execute the pictureBox2_Click
3. That basically my code there, only thing I did not put (that i think is not relevant) are making Labels and ComboBox disabled  and not visible.
4. I did try change it back to Control (BackColor) but same problem.